# Multiple inputs with arrays using String - Names

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a program that will have a user enter a list of tutor names.  Only up to 10 peer tutors may be hired. Then, the program will present each name, based on a list alphabetized by last name. This is what I have so far, but it does not work and I don't know what to do. I need it to continue to run until I stop it and continue with more of the program.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Report {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

          int numTutors = 10;
          String[] listNames = getTutorNames();
    }

    public static String[] getTutorNames() {

          String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String[] listNames = new String[10];

        for (int x = 0; x < listNames.length; x++) {
            firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Tutor's First Name: ");
            lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Tutor's Last Name: ");

            if (firstName.equals("")) &&  lastName.equals("")) {
                break; // loop end
            }
            listNames[x] = lastName + ", " + firstName;
        }
        return listNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, you need to use:
`if (firstName.equals("") &&  lastName.equals(""))`
instead of:`if((firstName == (" ")) &&  lastName == (" "))`

Comment: Do you need *up to* 10 tutors, or *exactly* 10 tutors?

Comment: then see my answer for how you can return the right size array.

Comment: My suggestion is, break your problem into smaller pieces, and try to actually write compilable and runnable code to deal with those small problems:  e.g. first write a program that read a string (to make it simple, only name, instead of first and last name) and then print it out.  Once u make it works, then store the name in an array, and after u read all names, print out data in the array.  Then change your app to read first + last name.  Then add sorting feature.  Each of the above should be easy enough for you to solve if u have basic capability. Even u need to ask, u r asking sth specific

Comment: PeerTutorReport.java:23: error: illegal start of expression
            if (firstName.equals("")) && lastName.equals("")) {
                                      ^
PeerTutorReport.java:23: error: ';' expected
            if (firstName.equals("")) && lastName.equals("")) {
                                                            ^             im getting these errors

Comment: @AngieMckenzie For these kind of obvious problems you should resolve it yourself.  Just check the bracket to see if they are matching.  "Beginner" is not the excuse for being lazy

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a first.  IntelliJ didn't format the code correctly when I edited it, and I soon discovered this hit-list of errors.  Just bear in mind - the code won't even *compile*, let alone *run*, until these are fixed.

- `int numTutors` comes out of nowhere.  If you want to define it, then do so outside of the method call and set it to an appropriate value.

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int numTutors = 10;
      String[] listNames = getTutorNames(numTutors);
  }
  ```
- These declarations are invalid:

  ```
  String = firstName;
  String = lastName;
  ```

  You need some sort of variable name in between `String` and `=`.

  You're also not matching the contract for what you're passing in to `getTutorNames` - either what you pass in or what you accept must change.  I'm thinking that it's the latter.
- You can't use `==` to compare `String`.  You *have* to use `.equals()`.  Which leads me to...
- Your break is outside of your loop.  Move it inside of the loop.

  ```
  for (int x = 0; x < listNames.length; x++) {
      firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Tutor's First Name: ");
      lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Tutor's Last Name: ");
      if (firstName.equals(" "))&&lastName.equals(" ")){
          break; // loop end
      }
  }
  ```

  ..and *that* leads me to...
- You don't put the values anywhere through the loop!  You're just running the same code ten times!  Place them into the array.

  ```
  // after you check to see if the firstName and lastName are blank
  listNames[x] = firstName + lastName; // I don't know what you want to do with them from here.
  ```
- There is no `.add()` for an array.  The above is how you enter elements into an array.
- Your `return` is outside of your method block entirely.  Move it into your method.

---

Now, these are the issues that I could find.  Work on the compilation issues *first*, then one may talk about errors in code logic.  If you can, snag a quiet moment and ensure you understand variable declaration and `String` comparison.  I would *strongly* recommend the reading material found in [the Java wiki tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info).

Comment: It's okay.  We all start off as beginners.  We struggle through the meaning of this syntax and try to figure out how to express what we want to accomplish in a foreign, irregular language.  My criticism may seem a bit harsh, but understand that only by experiences like this can one hope to improve themselves as a programmer and developer.

Comment: One more thing (you beat me to most of the errors, so I figured I'd delete my post): I think the OP means empty strings instead of spaces.

Comment: @AngieMckenzie most of the problems are gone, but you need to fix the .add as well.

Comment: and yes empty strings, for example if the user were to enter no input for both last name and first name, the program will end and move on to the next step

Comment: @JakobWeisblat:  My inspection was syntactical, not logical.  I don't like seeing red squiggles in my IDE.  Empty string is easily accomplished with `""` instead of `" "`.

Comment: @AngieMckenzie:  No, still incorrect.  What is the signature of your method, what are you passing to it, and what should that argument be used to define?

Comment: @Jakob weisblat what do u mean, i thought i fixed it ? im not sure really

Comment: @AngieMckenzie now you did. Though it might be a good idea to put a `+ ", " +` in between the lastName and firstName

Comment: @makoto the point of the method is to get the tutors last and first name then list the names you have inputted and later sort the last names alphabetically. im not sure what you are really saying.

Comment: What I mean is this:  You're telling the method to accept a cylinder, but it's expecting a square.  Notice the method signature - you're expecting that the calling method has pre-knowledge of the first and last name, when you're extracting that knowledge in the method itself.  What you *should* be passing is the size of the array, and then use that to initialize the array in the method. Tangentially, I'm not a fan of this `Arrays.copyOf` business.  Returning `listNames` is sufficient.

Comment: so use return listNames; ? and get rid of (String firstName, String lastName)?

Comment: i had return listNames; earlier

Comment: the size of the array is up to 10, it can be stop at 5 or 4 or 3 etc. thats why i added in the break statement

Comment: PeerTutorReport.java:23: error: illegal start of expression
            if (firstName.equals("")) && lastName.equals("")) {
                                      ^
PeerTutorReport.java:23: error: ';' expected
            if (firstName.equals("")) && lastName.equals("")) {
                                                            ^ im gettin these errors

Comment: I'm going to grumble about that method signature but it *works*.  You can get rid of the `int` declaration in `main` since it has no use.  The rest...it'd be a spot fix but I'm just biding time before SO kicks in and tells us to take it to chat, so I can finish helping with these little spot checks.

Comment: ok can u check the errors im getting? i dont know what to do. and THANK you! you have been such a big help.

Comment: Unless you renamed the object, I don't know what that is.  Highlighting line 23 would be beneficial.  Outside of that, in all actuality, this has gone well beyond the scope of the problem itself.  I can't really help you too much further without going wildly off-track and out of scope of this type of question.

Comment: line 23 is :                                                         if (firstName.equals("")) && lastName.equals("")) {

Comment: im getting those 3 little errors, idk what to fix to get it to compile

Comment: @Makoto btw i read in your profile, you're a Anime enthusiast.

Comment: @makoto can we move into chat?

Comment: Oh yeah.  You have to have a certain rep for that.  I plumb forgot.  Sorry, not much I can do about that.  I did just notice the error - you have an extra right-paren in `firstName.equals(""))`.

Comment: since you're an anime ethusiast have you ever watch grave of the fireflies?

Answer (score 0):

So sorry for making an answer for something this small  but your

```
If (firstName.equals("")) && lastName.equals("")) {
```

Should be replaced by

```
If ((firstName.equals("")) && lastName.equals(""))) {
```